# GCC links trigger seg fault when the program is executed

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have produced a program that works perfectly fine on Linux Mint and now i have to make it work on a IBM computer running on linux red hat. For the libraries i have put them into modules (i had to recompile SFML for red hat) but when i start my program, it provokes a segfault, here is what valgrind told me about that failure :

```
    Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==30230==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xE0
==30230==    at 0x55B5974: sf::priv::GlxContext::GlxContext(sf::priv::GlxContext*) (in /workfs/dev/libs/SFML-2-2.1/build/lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1)
```

Just before the segfault i have this strange error : xrandr cannot load extension for display.
This error still occurs when i try to start SFML examples
Here is the code which provokes the segfault :

```
//segfault ;
    this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(this->width, this->height), this->title,sf::Style::Close, settings);
```

It looks like SFML cant create an OpenGL content because xrandr is whining, does someone have an idea ? Could someone bring me light upon my problem :D ?

Comment: Looks to me like you dereference a nullpointer, but without any code...

Comment: the thing is my program works fine on linux mint so i don't think the code is the problem here...

Comment: When your program invokes UB, anything can happen. Do you somewhere get a pointer from some API and then use it unchecked? Such things ma work on one configuration but not on another.

Comment: ok i added the code that is responsable for the segfault, i have commented the part of the code where i reuse window so this is the only point where i use it and it fails.

Comment: where exactly is the line where it segfaults? which variable is the nullpointer that it tries to access? what are the values and types of the variables you present, and how did they come to live?

Comment: The segfault comes from the line just after the comment //segfault, it is not a question of nullpointer but the call of RenderWindow provokes the call you can see in valgrind and that fails (SFML function)

Comment: Might be SFML bug where it fails to create the GL context and de-refs nullptr?

Comment: you might be right but why would it fail to create GL context, other programms running on the calculator work fine.

Comment: Looks like someone needs to use a debugger on this.

Comment: Ok i have tried to load the OpenGL program with startx activated i have a problem "xrandr cannot load extension" before my segmentation fault

Comment: Please clarify your question; the root cause here is not the segfault but whatever causes xrandr to whine.

Comment: I have tried to refocus my question on the real problem : not the segfault but the xrandr bug thing thanks @MichaelFoukarakis